# Twilio Outbound Call Speech to Text

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

How does Twilio Speech Recognition work for outbound calls? For incoming calls, I'd assume creating Twilio functions under developers tools, handle with VoiceResponse and set the A CALL COMES IN option to the create function

Assume calling into an IVR system, listening to the IVR prompts, use Speech Recognition and then have twilio perform an action.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you [make an outbound call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), you need to [set a URL within the API request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters) that Twilio will make an HTTP request to to find out what to do once the call connects. From then it's basically the same as the inbound call.

You would return the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) TwiML with [`input` set to `speech`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-input) with an [`action` defined for the URL to call once the speech recognition has a full result](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action). You can use that URL to respond to further prompts from the IVR that you're calling, or do other things like [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) onto another number once you've, say, connected with an agent via the IVR.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks Philnash, this will get me started. The url on the action attribute points to a TwiML or i can have function url, use event.SpeechResult and perform an action?

Comment: The URL on the action attribute should point to the application you want to use to process the `SpeechResult`. That can be on your own server or a Twilio Function or anything. If you want the call to continue after the speech result is returned, then you need to return TwiML from that action too.

Comment: Thanks Philnash, I pointed it to a Twilio function and it works